# Why uninitialized local variable always has the same initial value?

Tags: c, static, local-variables

In this piece of code, why in my testing the result is always `1`, `2`, and `3`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test() {
    int a;
    a++;

    printf("%d",a);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    test();
    test();
    test();
}
```

I think the variable in `test()` is static, isn't it? And Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other answers told, your variable is not initialized. 
It prints 1, 2 and 3 possibly because of **your compiler compiled the code with `prolog(prologue)` that cleans the stack with zeros**.

The local variables in C, actually point to the offset on your stack, and the `stack frame` will be restored after the call is returned.

I googled and selected a artical randomly that told about this, see [[How function calls work?](http://abrickshort.wordpress.com/2005/04/)].

Here is a video talk about that [[Assembly Programming Assembly Function Stack Frame Explained](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcfQVwtoyHY) ] (again, selected randomly).

And Wikipedia explains the [[Call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)] as well.

Answer (score 9):

The variable is not static. You're accessing an uninitialized variable. The behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are working with an unintialize value... (random behaviour in this case).

Initialize your variable (example to 0) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test(){
    int a=0;
    a++;
    printf("%d",a);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    test();
    test();
    test();
}
```

Comment: It's quite complicated ! It could have been : 5, 8, 7. It's indeterminate ! 

Your variable 'a' could be : 0, the value it was before (probably your case) or even crash your program ! 

You always have to intialize variable.

You probably got a warning, don't you ?

Comment: @Leo.Dong, the reason you are seeing 1, 2, 3 is because the stack frame of `test` so happens to be laid out on exactly the same spot as before, effectively making `a` use its previous value. This is totally undefined behavior and not to be relied upon. You could try inserting a couple of function calls (such as `printf`) in between your `test()` calls and see that the uninitialized value of `a` actually gets affected by whatever is called before `test()`.

Answer (score 2):

No, your variable is not static at all!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597426/1758762

Static variables (file scope and function static) are initialized to zero:

```
int x; // zero
int y = 0; // also zero

    void foo() {
        static int x; // also zero
    }
```

Non-static variables (local variables) are indeterminate. Reading them prior to assigning a value results in undefined behavior.

```
void foo() {
    int x;
    printf("%d", x); // the compiler is free to crash here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the variable you are trying to print is not static and neither it is initialized , thus it is taking garbage value , which seems random to you , if you execute this program on a different machine ,then there you will have different output because there you will have different garbage value

in order to avoid it , you will have to initialize your variable with some value

Comment: is the garbage value depends on the machine?

Comment: garbage values are the values which are un-referenced values , which are still in your memory but have lost their reference , thus your compiler picks from any memory location , which for us is the garbage value